# Update atraves de inner join en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Como puedo pasar esta `query` a `Oracle`?, estoy actualizando un campo de una tabla A a través de un `inner join` con una tabla B:

```
UPDATE ATA
SET A.ID_IN = B.id_in
FROM TMP_TRF_ALL ATA
INNER JOIN items B
on ATA.seq=B.seq
WHERE ATA.PROCESADO = 1
AND  ATA.EXT = '213'
AND B.ID_COMPANY='1'
```

He realizado esto, pero no es correcto por que no actualiza y es como si quisiera actualizar el campo `ID_IN` de la tabla `items`, cuando en realidad quiero actualizar el campo `ID_IN` de la tabla `TMP_TRF_ALL`

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT ATA.id_in as T1IV,B.id_in AS T2IV FROM TMP_TRF_ALL ATA  INNER JOIN items B 
on ATA.seq=B.seq 
WHERE ATA.PROCESADO = 1 AND  ATA.EXT = '213' AND B.ID_COMPANY='1')T
SET T.T1IV=T.T2IV
```

Comment: El `update` que muestras debiera hacer el trabajo, quizás está teniendo problemas ubicando los registros que debe actualizar de vuelta, ¿has intentado incluir la llave primaria de la tabla `TMP_TRF_ALL` en el `select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una sentencia [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) para lograr el objetivo. En tu caso, quedaría algo como:

```
merge into TMP_TRF_ALL ATA
using (select * from items where ID_COMPANY = '1') B
   on (    ATA.seq = B.seq
       and ATA.Procesado = 1
       and ATA.EXT = '213'
      )
when matched then 
update
   set id_in = B.id_in;
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solucion